# How to fill pandas DataFrame (from .CSV) columns with calculations using values in the same rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have loaded a dataset from a .csv using `pd.read_csv()`. I now have a dataframe looking like this:

[Pandas dataframe from .csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXZvu.png)

What i need to achieve is basically this (shown in excel):

[excel sheet of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuKDS.png)

Other columns would be filled in the same manner but with different equations.

I am new in Python, but I've tried:

```python
for row in df.iterrows():
     if df.columns == ['μ(price)']:
          df.fillna(9)
```

just to try to fill it with 9s to see if this approach could theoretically work,but it kept returning an error

```python
ValueError: ('Shapes must match', (9,), (1,))
```

I've tried to search everywhere. Is there perhaps a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which is equivalent to [`IF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function in Excel.

Try this :

```
import numpy as np

df["µ(price)"] = np.where(df["Price"].gt(450), 0, (450 - df["Price"]).div(450 - 350))
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
  Are  Price Distance  µ(price)
0  o1    490      418      0.00
1  o2    481      371      0.00
2  o3    413      747      0.37
3  o4    313      506      1.37
4  o5    322      667      1.28
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Works like a charm for all the columns.